# Is `.bashrc` executed when ubuntu 18 logging in?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, login, bashrc

I added a line at the beginning of `.bashrc` which is:

```
exit
```

No terminal will be opened (the usual way), but Ubuntu 18.04 never been able to log in (to the user interface).

I was able to log in later by editing `.bashrc` from the **recovery mode** root terminal interface and deleting the `exit` statement.

My question:

> Does this mean that Ubuntu execute `.bashrc` when it logs in? ..
>
> If so, how to write a condition (`if` statement) for the *log_in* or *terminal_app* case alone?

Comment: `man bash | less -p ^FILES`

Comment: If your `.bashrc` is based on the default Ubuntu one, make sure any commands like `exit` are placed **after** the `case $- in ... esac` section if you want them to apply only in interactive shells

Comment: @steeldriver , it's working, .. the comment above (in `.bashrc`) explains it.
so, the `.bashrc` does execute in non-interactive way when logging in? (P.S: if you may explain this in an answer)

Comment: @YasinYousif TBH I don't really know enough to write a good answer - I *think* that it depends which display manager (`lightdm`,`gdm` etc.) is used and how exactly it invokes the user's chosen desktop session